# count number of api calls from classes.dex

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dalvik

I was wondering if it is possible to count the number of times an API is called by parsing the classes.dex file. I know ways to get all the API's called but wanted to know if there is a way to get the number of times an api was called without running the application, just by parsing the `classes.dex`. Is this information stored in dex file ?

I had quick look at dex file format but wasn't able to find that information.

Ex : if `substring()` is used once in class1 and class2 and class3 , I should be able to get information that substring has been called 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to tell how many times an API call is made by just parsing the code. For example, how many times is `foo()` called?:

```
public static void bar(int x) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

If you just look at the source code, the answer is *once* but if you analyze the semantics, the answer is `x` times.

If you only want to know the number of times an API call exists in the source code, you can get that easily.

1. Use [baksmali](https://bitbucket.org/JesusFreke/smali/downloads) on
   the dex file to get Smali code.
2. Grep (or ack) the Smali for the API call you want. Example regex for [SmsManager.sendTextMessage()](http://https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Ftelephony%2Fgsm%2FSmsManager.html%23sendTextMessage(java.lang.String%2C%2520java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20android.app.PendingIntent%2C%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is:

   ```
   "invoke[^,]+, Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;->sendTextMessage\(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;\)V"
   ```
3. Count the number of times you find that line. Something like:

   ```
   grep api_call_pattern . | wc -l
   ```

This can only be considered a rough proxy for actual API call counts. If you want something more accurate, you'll have to do symbolic analysis. Unfortunately, there isn't a turn-key solution for this that you can use that I'm aware of.